# Posts from specific WordPress category not displaying in Timber/Twig for loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twig, timber

I am using the following code to output posts from three different categories. The posts from Canada and World are being displayed correctly, but nothing from United States. I have tried dumping `var_dump($context['posts']);` in the WordPress PHP file, which does return the posts from all of the categories including United States. When I use Timber's `{{ dump(post) }}` in the Twig template to dump `{{ dump(posts.united-states) }}`, the following is displayed `int(0)`. I have tried removing the hyphen from the category slug and updating the `for loop`, but this did not solve the issue.

Any ideas on what is causing this issue?

**PHP code**

```
$context = Timber::context();
$timber_post = new Timber\Post();

$query = array(
  // Canada, United States, and World categories
  'cat' => '3,4,6',
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$posts = Timber::get_posts( $query );

$sorted_posts = array();

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
  // Get first category of post
  $category = $post->category();

  // Fill post back to sorted_posts
  $sorted_posts[ $category->slug ][] = $post;
}

// Add sorted posts to context
$context['posts'] = $sorted_posts;

$context['post'] = $timber_post;
Timber::render( array( 'page-' . $timber_post->post_name . '.twig', 'page.twig' ), $context );
```

**Twig template code**

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}
{% block content %}
<section>
  <h2>Canada</h2>
  {% for story in posts.canada %}
    <article class="story" id="story-{{ story.ID }}">
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
<section>
  <h2>United States</h2>
  {{ dump(posts.united-states) }}
  {% for story in posts.united-states %}
    <article class="story" id="story-{{ story.ID }}">
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
<section>
  <h2>The World</h2>
  {% for story in posts.world %}
    <article class="story" id="story-{{ story.ID }}"> 
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your tried accessing it with good old square brackets like below:

```
{{ dump(posts['united-states']) }}
```

Quick example: https://twigfiddle.com/pbqq14

Loop example:

```
{% for story in posts['united-states'] %}

{{story}}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Using brackets in the dump does work. Can the brackets be used in the `for loop`?

Comment: Yes, per the [Twig documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables) you can use square brackets to access array keys if they cannot be represented as normal PHP variables.

Comment: Yes, updated my example and the demo link example for the loop.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks. The square bracketed code worked.